# How do I add more than two Strings in "Map"? I want to add 5

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, hashmap

I'm doing a register and login and I want it to add more things into the database. Such as first name, Last name, email, username, and password. Here's my code for my register.java:

```
public class Register extends Activity {

private Button bRR;

EditText etFN, etLN, etEmail, etUN, etPW, etRPW;
Spinner SMonth, SDay, SYaer;
TextView TVterms;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
ProgressDialog PD;
String url = "http://10.0.0.12/accounts_java.php";
String fname , lname , uname , email , pass;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    initTypeface();

    //Button's go here
    bRR = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bRR);

    bRR = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bRR);
    bRR.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf"));
    //EditText's go here
    etFN = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etFN);
    etLN = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etLN);
    etEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etUN = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUN);
    etPW = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPW);
    etRPW = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etRPW);
    //Spinner's go here
    SMonth = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SMonth);
    SDay = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SDay);
    SYaer = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SYear);

    SMonth = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SMonth);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Month, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    SMonth.setAdapter(adapter);

    SDay = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SDay);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Day, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    SDay.setAdapter(adapter);

    SYaer = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SYear);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Year, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    SYaer.setAdapter(adapter);
    //TextView's go here
    TVterms = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVterms);
    //oonClick's go here
    //pd'// STOPSHIP: 12/18/2015
    PD = new ProgressDialog(this);
    PD.setMessage("Creating your account...");
    PD.setCancelable(false);
}



public void onSignUpClick(View v)
{
    if (v.getId() == R.id.bRR);
    {
        EditText fname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etFN);
        EditText lname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etLN);
        EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUN);
        EditText email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        EditText pass1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPW);
        EditText pass2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etRPW);

        String fnamestr = fname.getText().toString();
        String lnamestr = lname.getText().toString();
        String unamestr = uname.getText().toString();
        String emailstr = email.getText().toString();
        String pass1str = pass1.getText().toString();
        String pass2str = pass2.getText().toString();

        if (!pass1str.equals(pass2str))
        {
            //popup msg
            Toast pass = Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Password do not match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            pass.show();

        }

    }
}

private void initTypeface() {

    Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf");
    TextView tittleText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    tittleText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf");
    tittleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    tittleText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf");
    tittleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    tittleText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf");
    tittleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    tittleText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf");
    tittleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
    tittleText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf");
    tittleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
    tittleText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf");
    tittleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    tittleText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf");
    tittleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);
    tittleText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf");
    tittleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TVterms);
    tittleText.setTypeface(myTypeface);
}

public void insert(View view){

    PD.show();
    fname = etFN.getText().toString();
    lname = etLN.getText().toString();
    uname = etUN.getText().toString();
    email = etEmail.getText().toString();
    pass = etPW.getText().toString();

    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    PD.dismiss();
                    etFN.setText("");
                    etLN.setText("");
                    etUN.setText("");
                    etEmail.setText("");
                    etPW.setText("");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Your account is created!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            PD.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error creating your account!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams() {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
            params.put("fname",fname);

            return params;
        }
    };
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToReqQueue(postRequest);
}

}
```

I want to add 5 more values into MySQL not just one.

Comment: so use insert query.

Comment: where you have issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams() {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
            params.put("fname",fname);
            params.put("lname",lname );
            ...
            return params;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to leave my old answer below because I still argue that ContentProvider might be a good mechanism for you since it logically isolates the syncing mechanisms for network transmission/etc.

I didn't realize you were using Volley at first, I had forgotten that it even exists since I just teach the manual stuff, and never use the 'convenience methods', etc.

---

....because if so it is on the Android device isn't MySQL, Android uses SQLite3 as its internal Database.

If you want to insert multiple things into a database, then you need to call insert over and over between a .beginTransaction() and a .endTransaction(), this way the database will 'throw away' any inserts that are done if any single insert fails.

Now you might be wondering how to pass multiple sets of data to the method to do the inserts. For this you have 2 options. You can pass an array of Contentvalues, or you can pass an array (or a collection such as arraylist/etc) of custom POJOs (and my recommendation would be to have that POJO class have a 'getContentValues() method that reuturns a content values object from each POJO.)

But in either case you have to begin your transaction, loop through all the Contentvalues, and then end the transation.

[Android JAVADOC for SQLit SQLiteDatabase.insert(String, String, Contentvalues)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))

I personally NEVER write a DB that I don't immediately wrap by a ContentProvider in Android. Content Provider just gives a nicer separation of concerns/interface for me. (and then it is easy to add syncAdapters, accounts, and all that extra 'sugar' to make the data-store work wonders for you. But of course this depends on your target application, and the ones I write are almost by definition all networked.)